# SHIMx64.EFI not shown in BIOS

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have used Ubuntu from a live USB drive before, but now I want to install it permanently. I am looking for step-by-baby-step instructions, so that I can understand exactly where I have gone wrong.

I have just bought a Dell XPS13 running Windows 10, and I want to install Ubuntu to get a dual-boot laptop. I used Windows Disk Manager to shrink the Windows partition, and leave unallocated space. I follow the [instructions from the Dell Knowledge Base](http://www.dell.com/support/article/ca/en/cabsdt1/SLN297060/en) until I reach Figure 6. At this point, I see the options ...

BOOTx64.EFI
grubx64.efi

... in the Files panel, but there is no sign of SHIMx64.EFI. I have been able to boot into Ubuntu using grubx64.efi, but when I get to the Install Type screen, I do not see the options shown in [this screenshot](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-GMyMgXW8IWc/Vjfb1nsFDTI/AAAAAAAAKww/c5Whc7TC1cM/s1600/ubuntuinstall5.png).

Instead, the installer jumps directly to a screen similar to the partition table, but the table is completely blank, only `/dev/sda` is visible in the Device dropdown, and none of the buttons react ... except for Install Now, which complains (understandably) that no root is defined. Just before the Installation Type screen appears, the WiFi connection dies and "No network devices available" appears in the WiFi menu.

I have tried using both 14.04 and 16.04, and both Rufus and Universal-USB-Installer to create my bootable USB drive.

Is there a step that I have missed that will display SHIMx64.EFI as an option at the EFI Boot Selection step? If grubx64.efi works to boot into Ubuntu, then is there a step I have missed that will allow me to select the unallocated partition?

Thanks in advance for all insights that you can share.

---

EDIT: the log from Rufus 2.11.995 shows only two lines containing the string "shim" when used with ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso:

```
Extracting: F:\pool\main\s\shim\shim_0.8-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb (432.6 KB)
Extracting: F:\pool\main\s\shim-signed\shim-signed_1.17~16.04.1+0.8-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb (307.6 KB)
```

The same is true for ubuntu-14.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso:

```
Extracting: F:\pool\main\s\shim\shim_0.8-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb (432.6 KB)
Extracting: F:\pool\main\s\shim-signed\shim-signed_1.18~14.04.1+0.8-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb (307.2 KB)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What that page from the Dell website doesn't tell is that you have to go to `System configuration / SATA Operation` and switch from `RAID On` to `AHCI`.

Ubuntu will not be able to see the Dell XPS 13 SSD if you don't modify that option.

The rest of the installation procedure should proceed normally.
Also, note that the setting up of `SHIMx64.EFI` should be performed after the system installation, not before.

Comment: This works. I have got Ubuntu installed and running. Thank you. Hower, if I want to boot into Windows, I now have to make two changes in the BIOS: alter the boot order and alter the SATA operation. Is that what you would expect?

Comment: That's normal, because Windows does not support changing that option once it has been installed on your PC.  
The fastest way would be to reinstall Windows. However, you could modify some Windows' registry settings by opening `regedit`:       HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\storahci    "Error Control": DWORD = 0    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\storahci\StartOverride    
"0": DWORD = 0`
    
 
 
After restarting change immediately back to `AHCI` mode and it should work.

Comment: SATA operation is already configured as AHCI, but I don't see SHIMx64.EFI, When I installed Ubuntu 16.04

After the installation In Boot sequence, When I click on add boot option(USB removed), it shows `no file system found`

Answer (score 0):

To get shimx64, you need to `sudo apt-get install shim-signed`.